# how to add delivery slot in magento?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, delivery

delivery slots will be:

11am - 1pm
3 -5 pm
5 – 7 pm
7-9pm 
9-10:30 pm

User can choose any delivery slots for today and tomorrow .
Only those time slots will be available to choose which will have 3 hours difference in the later time and the time of placing the order
For eg. - If a person places an order at 4: 30 pm . then for today he can choose slots 
7-9 , 9-10.30 only and all slots for tomorrow. He cannot choose slot 5-7 pm as the later time is 7 and the difference is 2.5 hours

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like book your table.

I guess this can be done via attribute:

You can create around 10 options under Booking attribute.

- 11am - 1pm-Today
- 3 -5 pm-Today
- 5 – 7 pm-Today
- 7-9pm-Today
- 9-10:30 pm-Today
- 11am - 1pm-Tomorrow
- 3 -5 pm-Tomorrow
- 5 – 7 pm-Tomorrow
- 7-9pm-Tomorrow
- 9-10:30 pm-Tomorrow

Then based on the current time of server/system whatever suits you best, you can display the attributes.

Say you found via code current time = 3 , then you will need to add the condition that the drop down wil be shown from 5-7 pm-today, 7-9pm-today and so on..

I mean this logic can be used. Will need to write the code accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a new custom order attribute you can place at the "shipping" checkout step
and then save in the database for each new order via, say, observer.